# Correct Application of Inductive Hypothesis

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

To provide full context of the practice question I'm attempting, it is as follows:

> For every integer n such that n ≥ 8, there exist nonnegative integers a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> such that 3a<sub>n</sub> + 5b<sub>n</sub> = n.
>
> Write a proof of the claim using the strong form of mathematical induction with the integer 10 as breakpoint — such that that n = 8, n = 9 and n = 10 would all be considered in the basis.

This is my attempt at the proof, but I can't seem to get past applying the I.H. in order to reach my goal in the inductive step.

> **Basis** 
>   If n = 8, then 3a<sub>8</sub> + 5b<sub>8</sub> = 8 
>   If n = 9, then 3a<sub>9</sub> + 5b<sub>9</sub> = 9 
>   If n = 10, then 3a<sub>10</sub> + 5b<sub>10</sub> = 10
>
> **Inductive Hypothesis** 
>   Let k be an integer such that k ≥ 10. It is necessary and sufficient to use the following:
>
> - Inductive Hypothesis: 3a<sub>n</sub> + 5b<sub>n</sub> = n for every integer n such that 8 ≤ n ≤ k.
>
> **Inductive Claim** 
>  3a<sub>k+1 + 5bk+1</sub> = k+1

Now I have to complete the remainder of the proof but I'm not even sure if I was proving it correctly so far or how to complete it from where I'm at.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, in particular, there are $a_{k-2}$ and $b_{k-2}$ such that $3a_{k-2} + 5b_{k-2} = k-2$. Now add $3$ to both sides.

Comment: Am I allowed to add 3 with no restrictions arbitrarily?

Also, how would I be able to deduce a_k-2 and b_k-2 from my previous steps?

Comment: @man2006 You don;t deduce $a_{k-2}$ and $b_{k-2}$ You just assume that you have those numbers such that $3a_{k-2} + 5b_{k-2} = k-2$. Now, how can you change those two numbers such that that $3a_{k+1} + 5b_{k+1} = k+1$? What is the relation between $a_{k+1}$ and $a_{k-2}$, and what is the relation between $a_{k+1}$ and $a_{k-2}$?

Comment: In this case, the best way to change those two numbers would be through the application of the Inductive Hypothesis. The relation between both a_k+1 and a_k-2 would be through the base which is **a** if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @man2006 Because $3$ is a number, you can add it to everything. Why wouldn't you be able to add $3$ to something? More generally, because you can do anything you like to an equality, providing you apply the same function to the value of each side.  The existence of $a_{k-2}$ and $b_{k-2}$ follows immediately from the inductive hypothesis. You don't need to know anything about them other than that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

For the step, see answer by @user3482749

But other than the inductive step, you also need to show that you can find actual values for $a_n$ and $b_n$ (and the others) in your base cases to make sure these work!

For example, to satisfy that $3a_8+5b_8=8$, you can set $a_8=1$ and $b_8=1$

Now do this for the other base cases as well

Comment: Along the same lines, would I be able to set a_9 = 2 or any other number such that it satisfies the right hand side is equal to 9 and the same for b_9?

Comment: @man2006 Yes, you need to find non-negative integers that work. Though $a_9=2$ is not going to work ...

Comment: Got it, I just have to keep trying different numbers that work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @man2006 you're welcome :)